# Displaying one item from a ListView of many items like a SlotMachine

Tags: android, listview

I am new to android. I want to use ListView to display only one item at a time and there should be way to know that the slot is showing a particular item once the user stops scrolling. To be particular I want to make it look like slot machine. Please help me out! Thanks in advance!

Please find the image below:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OzNm.jpg

Comment: Make the listview height same as the row height.

Comment: ListView is not the way you should implement this. Even if u make it it will be more like chea/ heavy workaround. Better approach would be to implement custom view or use one of existing libraries. ;)

Comment: @arol_123 yeah that can be done. but how will you make sure the list moves by one step? you know what i mean? as in it shouldn't show half of previous item and half of next item in the viewing window. a proper slot machine. animation is not what i am looking for right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WheelView is what actually you are looking for. Check this link:

http://sunilsuthar02.blogspot.in/2012/10/wheel-view-demo-in-android.html

https://github.com/LukeDeighton/WheelView